# The solution of Schrodinger equation in an infinite wall with step potential???

Tags: physics

[Click Here for Image!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwIda.jpg)

I want to ask how to deal with the equation on $L/2 < x < L$ region.

The equation has a general form $C e^{-k_2 L/2} + D e^{k_2 L/2}$ on $L/2 < x < L$.

However, as there exists infinite barrier at $x = L$, we do have non-zero $D$.

Then the boundary condition at $x = L/2$ yields

$B e^{i k_1 L / 2} = C e^{-k_2 L/2} + D e^{k_2 L/2}$ ... (1)

and

$i k_1 B e^{i k_1 L / 2} = k_2( - C e^{-k_2 L/2} + D e^{k_2 L/2})$ ... (2)

However, dividing (1) with (2) would not cancel the RHS terms that we usually see in quantum physics textbooks.

Is there anyway to solve the Schrodinger equation in this setting?

Comment: Your proposed wave functions are incorrect. The variable $x$ is missing. Write down the correct wave functions, then apply the boundary conditions.

Comment: One strategy I like for such problems is to choose the basis functions as conveniently as possible. For instance: on the left interval we know that the wavefunction vanishes at the origin, so the basis $\{\sin k_1 x,\cos k_1x\}$ is convenient. For the right-hand interval, we can instead use the shifted basis $\{\sin[k_2(x-L)],\cos[k_2(x-L)]\}$ to enforce $\psi=0$ without much fuss.

Comment: Just realized that my last comment assumed $E>V_0$, so not applicable as written.

Comment: This is a stock problem in 10% of QM textbooks. Why are you here?